# MVC BCrypt.Verify allows different passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bcrypt

I have accidentally typed the wrong password and it has passed validation. I found out that passwords were saved with additional salts.

```
this.password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(prefixSalt + password + suffixSalt, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(9));
```

And the verification:

```
BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(prefixSalt + password + suffixSalt, this.password);
```

In this way passwords are truncated to 8 characters and anything after 8th character is ignored. Can this issue be fixed without requiring all users to change their passwords?

Comment: Why do you think passwords were truncated to 8 characters?

Comment: I don't know why. I tested without prefix and suffix and worked fine... but this is not my question. I'm only trying to avoid to change passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to reverse the process for bcrypt, it is a one-way algorithm. You could "fix" the data by following a process like:

```
if (BCrypt.Verify(password, storedHash)) {
    // Log on user
} else if (BCrypt.Verify(prefixSalt + password + suffixSalt, storedHash)) {
    this.password = BCrypt.HashPassword(password);
    // Save to database
    // Log on user
} else {
    // User details incorrect
}
```

However, if the password is being truncated (although I cannot see why that is - perhaps the bug is elsewhere in the code?), this will not work as it would initially allow anyone to set anyone else's password.

Short answer: **No**, you need to reset everyone's password.